# Insufficient Permission

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

befor i ask i want to introduce my first steps.

I used this for example: [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/php)

1. Install google/apiclient via composer
2. Create a project in Google Developers Console
3. Add credentials to my project
4. Upload client_secret.json to my webserver
5. Run the script & enter the code

```html
Credentials saved to /files/php-yt-oauth2.json
This channel's ID is UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw. Its title is Google Developers, and it has 125874726 views.
```

Now i want to list all videos of one playlist:

```html
function playlistItemsListByPlaylistId($service, $part, $params) {
    $params = array_filter($params);
    $response = $service->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems(
        $part,
        $params
    );

    print_r($response);
}

playlistItemsListByPlaylistId($service,
    'snippet',
    array('maxResults' => 1, 'playlistId' => 'ID'));
```

An get the following error:

```html
[23-Dec-2017 14:29:59 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
 in /html/sa/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Http/REST.php:118
```

I dont know whats going wrong and i hope someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors), `insufficientPermissions` means that the OAuth 2.0 token provided for the request specifies scopes that are insufficient for accessing the requested data. You may also check this [link](https://www.domsammut.com/code/php-server-side-youtube-v3-oauth-api-video-upload-guide/comment-page-7) for additional reference.